# Can I access content of subfolders within Dropbox App folder

Tags: java, c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've setup my first tiny demo app using the Dropbox API and am unable to see any contents of subfolders within the App folder. On the settings tab, I see:
Permission type: App folder (this app has read/write access only to files inside its folder).

My folder structure looks like this:

- /Apps/MyAppFolderName/Folder1/Folder2/File3
- /Apps/MyAppFolderName/Folder1/File2
- /Apps/MyAppFolderName/File1

My code looks just like the C# tutorial with no modifications:

```
async Task ListRootFolder(DropboxClient dbx)
{
    var list = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync(string.Empty);

    // show folders then files
    foreach (var item in list.Entries.Where(i => i.IsFolder))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D  {0}/", item.Name);
    }

    foreach (var item in list.Entries.Where(i => i.IsFile))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("F{0,8} {1}", item.AsFile.Size, item.Name);
    }
}
```

It only prints out File1 and Folder1; it never gets to File2 nor Folder2 (nor, by extension, File3).

Have I misunderstood the meaning of the App folder permission (in that it doesn't allow access to subfolders) or am I expected to invoke another part of the API to open subfolders? I tried to use the `ListFolderContinueAsync(list.Cursor)` method after completing the first iteration of `list.Entries` but it simply returned an empty enumerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm) won't return subfolders. To get subfolders (and all children), you should use the [`Recursive`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/P_Dropbox_Api_Files_ListFolderArg_Recursive.htm) parameter on [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm), for example:

```
var list = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync(string.Empty, true);
```

This is preferred over calling `ListFolderAsync` for each subfolder individually.

In either case though, make sure you check [`HasMore`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/P_Dropbox_Api_Files_ListFolderResult_HasMore.htm) and call back to [`ListFolderContinueAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderContinueAsync_1.htm) if necessary, per the [`ListFolderAsync` documentation](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the contents of subfolders if you pass the subfolder name to the `ListFolderAsync` method:

```
var list = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync(@"/Folder1/Folder2");
```

The name must be prefixed with '/'.